# getting the localName of XML node

Tags: java, android, xml-parsing

I have an xml which looks like

```
<Personnel>
  <Employee type="permanent">
        <Name>Seagull</Name>
        <Id>3674</Id>
        <Age>34</Age>
   </Employee>
  <Employee type="contract">
        <Name>Robin</Name>
        <Id>3675</Id>
        <Age>25</Age>
    </Employee>
  <Employee type="permanent">
        <Name>Crow</Name>
        <Id>3676</Id>
        <Age>28</Age>
    </Employee>
</Personnel>
```

I'm trying to get the name of each node and then to take the values from there but I'm always getting null or empty string when I'm doing the following:

child.getLocalName().equals("permanent")

It throws exception because child.getLocalName() is null
I checked the child in the debugger and I saw that localName = "permanent"

Does anyone familiar with this strange behavior?

Comment: Are you trying to take value of each <name> node?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try can try using the following...

```
DOM Parser

SAX Parser

Pull Parser

JAXP AND JAXB

Castor
```

**Here is a snippet of code on how to use DOM Parser.....**

```
DocumentBuilderFactory odbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder odb =  odbf.newDocumentBuilder();
            InputSource is = new InputSource(new StringReader(xml));
            Document odoc = odb.parse(is);
            odoc.getDocumentElement().normalize ();    // normalize text representation
            System.out.println ("Root element of the doc is " + odoc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());
            NodeList LOP = odoc.getElementsByTagName("locations");
            int totalPersons =LOP.getLength();
            System.out.println("Total nos of locations:"+totalPersons);

            for(int s=0; s<LOP.getLength() ; s++)
            {
                Node FPN =LOP.item(s);
                if(FPN.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE)
                    {

                    Element latlon = (Element)FPN;                                                                // Change 1

                    NodeList oNameList1 = latlon.getElementsByTagName("featured");                                       // Change 2
                    Element firstNameElement = (Element)oNameList1.item(0);
                    NodeList textNList1 = firstNameElement.getChildNodes();
                    //this.setLocationId(((Node)textNList1.item(0)).getNodeValue().trim());    // Change 3
                    featuredArr = changeToBoolean(((Node)textNList1.item(0)).getNodeValue().trim());                                    // value taken
                    System.out.println("#####The Parsed data#####");
                    System.out.println("featured : " + ((Node)textNList1.item(0)).getNodeValue().trim());            // Change 4
                    System.out.println("#####The Parsed data#####");
```